# Getting compiling error when running yarn storyboook

Tags: webpack, babeljs, storybook

I am trying to use storybook in my app but seem to be getting some compiling errors whenever I import a component from my components library.

If I import just the specific component into my story from its source path like `import { BasicInformationCard } from '@myapp/components/src/components/BasicInformationCard';` I have no errors, however, once I import it from the root of my components library like `import { BasicInformationCard } from '@myapp/components';` my storybook won't compile.

Whenever I do that I get the following error:
`Module parse failed: The keyword 'private' is reserved (14:72). File was processed with these loaders: ../../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.`

My app is a CRA SPA that is inside a mono-repo that also holds a components library and a shared logic library. I think one of the components might be importing something from the shared library which has a complied class in it which is causing the error.

I can see where to update my babel and webpack settings for storybook but I am not sure how to resolve this error that is specific to my storybook. The app uses a `config-overrides.js` file to add certain presets and plugins to my webpack so I am wondering if I need a way to import that into my `.storybook/main.js` file maybe?

I am a little lost here as webpack/babel always confuses me.

Updated:
The index file for my components just looks like this:

```
export * from './components/header';
export * from './components/footer';
export * from './components/switch';
export * from './components/icon';
```

Comment: This does not seem like a webpack issue.
It is probably an import issue. Share your index file from components.
@brady

Comment: @Sultan I've updated the description to include that, thanks!

Comment: It is possible you are using a common component name in multiple files.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export